# WordPress - Issues with referencing custom PHP class in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I apologize if this is really dumb/obvious but this is my first experience working with classes in WordPress.

I made a class called `SharpSpringService.php` inside my custom plugin `sharpspring-form`. I placed the class within a classes folder within that custom plugin for organization purposes.

I'm referencing the `SharpSpringService` class within a function in `functions.php` but am getting an error. When I declare a new instance of `SharpSpringService` and place the account ID and secret key as parameters, I get a message: "Expected SharpSpring, got string". I also see an Internal Server 500 Error in the Chrome dev consoles that seems to be a result of creating an instance of this class.

I'm not sure why the parameters are expected to be "SharpSpring" as they should be accountID and secretkey.

Here is the `SharpSpringService` class:

```
    private $authError = false;
    private $accountID = null;
    private $secretKey = null;

    /**
     * SharpSpringService constructor.
     * @param $accountID SharpSpring Account ID
     * @param $secretKey SharpSpring Secret Key
     */
    public function __construct($accountID, $secretKey)
    {
        $this->accountID = $accountID;
        $this->secretKey = $secretKey;
    }

    public function hasAuthError() {
        return $this->authError;
    }

    public function makeCall($method, $params = []) {
        $requestID = session_id();
        $accountID = $this->accountID;
        $secretKey = $this->secretKey;

        $data = array(
            'method' => $method,
            'params' => $params,
            'id' => $requestID,
        );

        $queryString = http_build_query([
            'accountID' => $accountID,
            'secretKey' => $secretKey
        ]);

        $url = "http://api.sharpspring.com/pubapi/v1/?$queryString";

        $data = json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $resultObj = json_decode($result);

        if ($resultObj->error != null) {
            throw new \Exception($result->error);
        }
        return $resultObj;
    }
}
```

And here is the function in functions.php that is referencing the class:

```
function get_memberships_callback(){
    $newsListID = 550280195;
    $listName = "NewsList";
    $contactEmail = $_POST['contactemail'];
    $sharpSpringService = new SharpSpringService('[redacted]', '[redacted]'); //this is where the code chokes
    $return = [];
    if($contactEmail != null && $contactEmail !=""){
        $lists = $sharpSpringService->makeCall('getListMemberships', [
            'emailAddress' => $contactEmail,
        ]);

        if (count($lists) > 0) {
            $listArray = json_decode(json_encode($lists), true);
            $inNewsList = false;
            foreach($listArray as $list){

                if($list = $newsListID){
                    //the user is subscribed to the news list
                    $inNewsList = true;
                    $converted_result = ($inNewsList) ? 'true' : 'false';
                }
            }
        }
        $return[] = array(
            "status" => $converted_result,
            "list" => $listName
        );
        return json_encode($return);
    }
    else{
        return $return;
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: have you include your new class in functions.php ?

Comment: No, I have not. I haven't registered a custom class in WP before.

Comment: Wp don't know about you new class. Require it at the top of the functions.php with `require_once(path_to_your_class.php);`

Comment: It seems to only accept this if I literally include the full path, which doesn't seem right: `require_once('/Users/[me]/Projects/my-site/wp-content/plugins/sharpspring-form/classes/SharpSpringService.php');`

Comment: I ended up just moving the class to the Includes directory in my themes folder, and that seems to work: `require_once('includes/SharpSpringService.php')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calling numerous files, it is sometimes convenient to define a constant:

```
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
include( MY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'includes/admin-page.php');
include( MY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'includes/classes.php');
```